# Check if the value is in range between closest array's elements. (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, algorithm, date

I need to know how would I check if my given value is between two closest array's members. For example I have an array of dates with the date of week start in given period of time. And I need to check if my given date is in one of its week. For example:

1. 2015-11-02
2. 2015-11-09
3. 2015-11-16
4. 2015-11-23

And my given value is 2015-11-11 for example. How should I check if it is one of these weeks date? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%w(2015-11-02 2015-11-09 2015-11-16 2015-11-23).any? do |date| 
  date.to_date.cweek == Date.today.cweek
end
```

And here is what this does:
First, you have an array of strings, you use `any?` to loop through it and check if any fulfils a requirement, then you cast you date strings into actual dates, and cweek gives you the number of a week in the year. Date.today gives you today's date.

Instead of `Date.today.cweek` you can use `'2015-11-11'.to_date.cweek`.

The loop above returns boolean; you could also get an array of values that fulfil a condition like this:

```
new_array = %w(2015-11-02 2015-11-09 2015-11-16 2015-11-23).map do |date| 
  date.to_date.cweek == '2015-11-11'.to_date.cweek
end.compact
```

Resources:

- [Date class on ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)
- [Date & Time in Ruby on tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm)

---

UPDATE

If you want to get from the database only records with a date from particular week, this is how you could do it:

```
my_date = '2015-11-11'.to_date
matching_records = MyResource.where( date: my_date.beginning_of_week..my_date.end_of_week )
```

The assumptions are that you have a model `MyResource`, and that it has a column `date`. What this does is returns a relation with all the records that have dates from the same week as `my_date`.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need. One issue is that i need to check if years also equals, not only weeks. :) but thanks. I'll come somehow with an idea how to check if the years of to dates are equal :)

Comment: you just ask the date: '2015-11-11'.to_date.year

Comment: I have added couple of links to the answer where you may find out more about the methods of the Date.

Comment: thanks, if this idea will work for me ill check it as an answer to my question

Comment: I have an issue because my checking value of date is selected from database and I can't use these methods to_date or cweek because I get an error. I tried to use DATETIME to game to_date format and then use cweek. But it converted to string and I can't use cweek method. Any ideas how should I fix it?

Comment: That is something you failed to mention, you said a ruby array, not database. For database a different course of action should be taken. I will update my answer.

Comment: actually dates is an array, but checking value is taken from database. Sorry for my bad, I am new.

Comment: There is no reason why casting a date from a database to Date should not work. Please check your code. `User.first.created_at.to_date.class`
=> `Date`

Comment: Actually you updated different because my value i want to check is taken from database and the week dates are an array. You updated answer with opposite case or I don't get it

Comment: :-) obviously we don't understand each other fully. Can you please update your question with more details, what exactly you need, what you have (in terms of relevant models and columns), what you tried, and what fails (with an error message included).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892260/undefined-method-to-date-for-nilnilclass-error maybe from here you will fully understand what problems I face to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates array is sorted:

```
date >= dates.first && date <= dates.last
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with strings, you can "require 'date'" and transform your strings to dates ("Date.parse('2001-02-03')").

As others have suggested, you can then see if your date is between the first and last entry of your list.

If the real list is sorted and each entry is one week apart, then you can easily find where in the list your guy is.

E.g., say the list is [date_0, date_1, date_2, ..., date_k] (all 1 week apart), and you're given a test_date between date_0 and date_k. Then (test_date.jd - date_0.jd)/7 gives you the index of the date in your list that is <= test_date.